# I have downloaded solana and rust and am trying to anchor build a project and keep getting this message

Tags: anchor, cargo, config

error[E0635]: unknown feature `proc_macro_span_shrink`
--> /Users/arslandin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/proc-macro2-1.0.47/src/lib.rs:92:30
|
92 |     feature(proc_macro_span, proc_macro_span_shrink)